# Racket - define one character with token-char

Tags: parsing, token, racket

I am working on a project for a class and we are tasked with writing a scanner for numbers, symbols, comments, arithmetic operators, parenthesis, and EOF in both Python and Racket. I am working on the racket version and I have written the following line to define one or more character as a symbol:

```
[(any-char) (token-CHAR (string->character lexeme))]
```

I have the following line to define on  or more digits as a number:

```
[(:+ digit) (token-NUM (string->number lexeme))]
```

I am very new to Racket, this is my third program, so I am not exactly sure how to approach this, so any suggestions are greatly appreciated. I have scoured the Racket documentation, but I wasn't able to find what I was looking for.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a minimal getting-started example - heavily commented.

```
#lang racket
;;; IMPORT
;; Import the lexer tools 
(require parser-tools/yacc
         parser-tools/lex
         (prefix-in : parser-tools/lex-sre)  ; names from lex-sre are prefixed with :
         ;                                     to avoid name collisions
         syntax/readerr)

;;; REGULAR EXPRESSIONS

;; Names for regular expressions matching letters and digits.
;; Note that :or are prefixed with a : due to (prefix-in : ...) above
(define-lex-abbrevs
  [letter     (:or (:/ "a" "z") (:/ #\A #\Z) )]
  [digit      (:/ #\0 #\9)])

;;; TOKENS

;; Tokens such as numbers (and identifiers and strings) carry a value
;; In the example only the NUMBER token is used, but you may need more.
(define-tokens value-tokens (NUMBER IDENTIFIER STRING))

;; Tokens that don't carry a value.
(define-empty-tokens op-tokens (newline :=  = < > + - * / ^  EOF))

;;; LEXER

;; Here the lexer (aka the scanner) is defined.
;; The construct lexer-src-pos evaluates to a function which scans an input port
;; returning one position-token at a time.

;; A position token contains besides the actual token also source location information
;; (i.e. you can see where in the file the token was read)

(define lex
  (lexer-src-pos
   [(eof)                                            ; input: eof of file     
    'EOF]                                            ; output: the symbol EOF

   [(:or #\tab #\space #\newline)                    ; input: whitespace
    (return-without-pos (lex input-port))]           ; output: the next token
   ;                                                           (i.e. skip the whitespace)

   [#\newline                                        ; input: newline
    (token-newline)]                                 ; ouput: a newline-token   
   ;                                                 ; note:  (token-newline) returns 'newline

   [(:or ":=" "+" "-" "*" "/" "^" "<" ">" "=")       ; input:  an operator
    (string->symbol lexeme)]                         ; output: corresponding symbol

   [(:+ digit)                                       ; input:  digits
    (token-NUMBER (string->number lexeme))]))        ; outout: a NUMBER token whose value is
;                                                    ;         the number
;                                                    ; note:   (token-value token)
;                                                              returns the number

;;; TEST

(define input (open-input-string "123+456"))

(lex input) ; (position-token (token 'NUMBER 123) (position 1 #f #f) (position 4 #f #f))
(lex input) ; (position-token '+ (position 4 #f #f) (position 5 #f #f))
(lex input) ; (position-token (token 'NUMBER 456) (position 5 #f #f) (position 8 #f #f))
(lex input) ; (position-token 'EOF (position 8 #f #f) (position 8 #f #f))


;; Let's make it a little easier to play with the lexer.

(define (string->tokens s)
  (port->tokens (open-input-string s)))

(define (port->tokens in)
  (define token (lex in))
  (if (eq? (position-token-token token) 'EOF)
      '()
      (cons token (port->tokens in))))

(map position-token-token (string->tokens "123*45/3"))   ; strip positions
; Output:

; (list (token 'NUMBER 123)
;        '*
;        (token 'NUMBER 45)
;        '/
;        (token 'NUMBER 3))
```